# How I can get the 'n' possible matrices from two vectors?

Tags: algorithm

I've been searching for an algorithm for the solution of all possible matrices of dimension 'n' that can be obtained with two arrays, one of the sum of the rows, and another, of the sum of the columns of a matrix. For example, if I have the following matrix of dimension 7:

```
matriz= [ 1  0  0  1  1  1  0
          1  0  1  0  1  0  0
          0  0  1  0  1  0  0
          1  0  0  1  1  0  1
          0  1  1  0  1  0  1
          1  1  1  0  0  0  1
          0  0  1  0  1  0  1 ]
```

The sum of the columns are:

> col= [4  2  5  2  6  1  4]

The sum of the rows are:

> row = [4  3  2  4  4  4 3]

Now, I want to obtain all possible matrices of "ones and zeros" where the sum of the columns and the rows fulfil the condition of "col" and "row" respectively.

I would appreciate ideas that can help solve this problem.

Comment: Can you say a little more about what you are looking for?  for example, I am interpreting the first row of Matriz as binary 1101010 == decimal 106, not 4.

Comment: This is more of a linear algebra question than a programming question.  It should probably be on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Show example code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: So, you want it in C++, C#, Matlab or what?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the application? Some type of puzzle?

Comment: Do you want all possible matrices as output or just a count of them? Those are 2 rather significantly different problems.

Comment: @bcrist I'm not sure how you'd generate these without programming, and if it's programming, it probably doesn't belong on [math.se].

Comment: @Dukeling Surely a very bored person with lots of paper and time could do it without even touching a computer.  If the question had indicated that some programming had been attempted, it would fit here, but none was provided.  If any math problems that *could* be solved by programming a computer don't belong on math.stackexchange.com that leaves a relatively small set of topics for discussion there...

Comment: @bcrist I agree that it doesn't fit here because it doesn't show an attempt at solving the problem oneself, but that doesn't mean it fits on [math.se]. I doubt OP is 'a very bored person with lots of paper and time'.

Comment: @Dukeling Well the brute-force solution involves little math, but I interpreted the question as looking for an efficient solution.  In my opinion, the typical user on Math is much more likely to be able to provide one than the typical user on SO.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious way is to brute-force a solution: for the first row, generate all the possibilities that have the right sum, then for each of these, generate all the possibilities for the 2nd row, and so on. Once you have generated all the rows, you check if the sum of the columns is right. But this will take a lot of time. My math might be rusty at this time of the day, but I believe the number of distinct possibilities for a row of length `n` of which `k` bits are 1 is given by the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) or [`nchoosek(n,k)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) in Matlab. To determine the total number of possibilities, you have to multiply this number for every row:

```
>> n = 7;
>> row= [4 3 2 4 4 4 3];
>> prod(arrayfun(@(k) nchoosek(n, k), row))
ans =
   3.8604e+10
```

This is a lot of possibilities to check! Doing the same for the columns gives

```
>> col= [4 2 5 2 6 1 4];
>> prod(arrayfun(@(k) nchoosek(n, k), col))
ans =
   555891525
```

Still a large number, but 'only' a factor 70 smaller.

It might be possible to improve this brute-force method a little bit by seeing if the later rows are already constrained by the previous rows. If in your example, for a particular combination of the first two rows, both rows have a 1 in the second column, the rest of this column should all be 0, since the sum must be 2. This reduces the number of possibilities for the remaining rows a bit. Implementing such checks might complicate things a bit, but they might make the difference between a calculation that takes 2 days or one that takes just 1 hour.

An optimized version of this might alternatively generate rows and columns, and start with those for which the number of possibilities is the lowest. I don't know if there is a more elegant solution than this brute-force method, I would be interested to hear one.

Comment: Thanks Bas Swinckels, I was doing the same, I hope also know some other more efficient method

Comment: So is your code fast enough, or does it take forever? And did you use the extra tricks I proposed? Please upvote or accept if you are happy with the answer.

Comment: @RaúlEmirGutiérrezLópez You say you were doing that same - for future reference, you should include that attempt in your question to start with.